# Connection GPS to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, nmea

I am attempting to read the NMEA output of a GPS module with an Atmega1284p UART. This is what the incoming ascii stream looks like:

```
$GPGLL,3720.11677,N,12158.43719,W,031059.00,A,D*77<CR><LF>
```

I want to grab the "3720.11" portion of the string, which is latitude. This is not the only string coming in, but it's the only one with "GPGLL" in it, so I've written some code that grabs characters at the uart until it sees an L, then it looks for the comma at the start of the number. Then it grabs the characters after that, ignoring the decimal.

I don't know how to write this program in Python.
Please help me!

```c
char ignore;
char latitude[6];

while(ignore!=0x4C)
{
    ignore=getchar();        // Look for L (4C) at start of string
}           

while(ignore!=0x2C)
{
    ignore=getchar();        // Look for comma (2C) before latitude data
}                         

latitude[0]=getchar();       // Store latitude characters
latitude[1]=getchar();
latitude[2]=getchar();
latitude[3]=getchar();
ignore=getchar();            // Ignore decimal
latitude[4]=getchar();
latitude[5]=getchar();
```

Comment: What is the code that you mentioned have you written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you can use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to split a string into a list given a delimiter. In your string comma is the delimiter. So split the string, get the second element in the list and you have the latitude:

```python
def get_latitude_from_nmea(telegram):
    split_telegram = telegram.split(',')
    latitude = split_telegram[1]

    return latitude

# example:

telegram = "$GPGLL,3720.11677,N,12158.43719,W,031059.00,A,D*77"
latitude = get_latitude_from_nmea(telegram)

print(latitude)     # 3720.11677
```

`latitude` is a string. If you want it as a float you can cast it with `float()`.